# Carregar pagina antes de ser chamada

Tags: javascript

No meu seguinte exemplo, tenho um button que chama atraves do window.location uma pagina que demora um certo tempo a carregar. Estou a tentar criar um codigo javascript que carregar ja a pagina antes de ser chamada e que apareça uma label "loading" na pagina do button e depois sim redireccionar para a outra pagina

```
<label id="lbl"></label>
<input type="button" value="demo" id="btn_demo">

<script>
 var btn = document.getElementById("btn_demo");

 btn.onclick = function() {myFunction()};

 function myFunction() {

     document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = "LOADING!";

     if page == "loaded" {
        window.location.href="demo_load.htm";
     }  
    //call page
 }
```

Comment: Veja se pode te ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/a/25253988

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso?

```
<script>
    var goTo = function(){
        document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = "LOADING!";
        window.location.href="demo_load.php";
    }
</script>

<label id="lbl"></label>
<input type="button" value="demo" id="btn_demo" onclick="goTo()">
```

demo_load.php:

```
<?php
//Apenas para simular um processamento
sleep(5);

echo 'vim';
```